# Angular4 routing: append string to dynamic parameter in path

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have created routes like this

```
/home/display-cityname/
```

Right now I hardcoded all the city names I have and made different routes for all the cities, If I want to pass the city name dynamically, I can do something like this

```
/home/:cityname/
```

but I want that 'display' string to be appended for every city. Is there any approach where I can append the city name to that string itself? Something like this /home/display-{cityname}. I didn't find any solution where we can append a string to dynamic values in the route itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a matcher: instead of "path" in the route properties, you do something like this:

```
export function displayCities(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.startsWith('display-')
    ? ({consumed: url})
    : null;
}

export const routes = [{ matcher: displayCities, component: CityComponent }];
```

https://angular.io/api/router/Route#matcher

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher